# Google Cloud REST API - How can return compute engine images newer than a specified creationTimestamp?

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google's Cloud API to only return disk images (compute.instances.list) created after a certain date.

I'm using the following for the `filter` parameter: `creationTimestamp > 2019-08-02` but it's not working. I'm getting `Invalid value for field 'filter': 'creationTimestamp \u003e 2019-08-02'. Invalid list filter expression.`

Any ideas, or is it not possible? I can have it work using a partial date & a wildcard, using `creationTimeStamp = 2019-08-0*`, but that's not the same as `everything after this date`.

Comment: You are talking about disk images, but you pointed to `compute.instances.list`. In any case, it is exactly the same as posted in my answer: just use the command `gcloud compute images` instead of `gcloud compute instances`, and the result will be the desired but for the images instead of the instances.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue by Google Cloud Platform, and you can follow it progress [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/132365111).

As an alternative, you could use a `gcloud` command. You could first format the list as, for instance, a table, and then use one of the columns (that will be the creation time stamp) to filter.

The following command

```
gcloud compute instances list --format="table(name,creationTimestamp)" --filter="CREATION_TIMESTAMP > 2019-08-23"
```

will give you a list of Compute Engine instances created after `2019-08-23` and, in this case, you will only obtain pear each GCE instance their name and the creation date.

This [blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/filtering-and-formatting-fun-with) is very interesting and educational about how to use filter, formats, tables and more regarding `gcloud` commands.